# Laravel 5.5 cannot login using auth scaffolding

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, controller, laravel-blade

I am making register - login feature on my app after installing auth scaffolding and creating database for storing credentials that using no other than username and password. I have successfully registered new account, stored into database, and redirected to Admin page. But after logout, i cannot do login with previous account that i created and it shows error message like this..

[Error message that prevent login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEwKH.png)

what should i do?

Here are my:

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'FrontController@home')->name('home');

Route::get('/login', 'FrontController@login')->name('login');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin');

Route::get('/manual', 'ManualLoginController@manual')->name('manual');

Route::get('/logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
```

**LoginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function logout(Request $request) {
          Auth::logout();
          return redirect('/login');
    }

}
```

**login.blade.php**

```
<div class="container-fluid-full">         
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="login-box">
            <div class="icons">
                <a href="/"><i class="halflings-icon home"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="halflings-icon cog"></i></a>
            </div>
            <h2 style="font-family: 'Raleway'; font-weight: 800">Masuk sebagai administrator</h2>
            @if ($errors->any()) 
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
            @endif
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('login')}}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="input-prepend" title="Username">
                        <label for="username">{{ __('Username') }}</label>

                        <span class="add-on"><i class="halflings-icon user"></i></span>

                        <input class="input-large span10 form-control{{ $errors->has('username') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="username" id="username" type="text" placeholder="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required autofocus/>

                        @if ($errors->has('username'))
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('username') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>


                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    <div class="input-prepend" title="Password">
                        <label for="password">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                        <span class="add-on"><i class="halflings-icon lock"></i></span>

                        <input class="input-large span10 form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required/>

                        @if ($errors->has('password'))
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    <div class="button-login">  
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> {{ __('Login') }}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div><!--/span-->
    </div><!--/row-->
</div>
```

**RegisterController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:4|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

**FronController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FrontController extends Controller
{
    public function home () {
        return view ('home');
    }

    public function login () {
        return view ('login');
    }

}
```

**AdminController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default laravel use `email` field for authentication, you can overwrite it by defining the below function in your login controller

```
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

For details you can check in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` trait

Comment: Wohooo you are my savior! Thank you bro! :D